# Update android app in background when new version uploaded to playstore

Tags: android

How can I update app in background when an new version is available on google play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that when you are distributing apps over Google play Store. Triggering of auto update depends on user's preference and settings.

If you wish to restrict users from using older version of app you can implement your custom implementation using server API to determine update required and when user is using your app prompt him to update. Alternatively you can also post Notification.

Whenever user performs action on the Notification/Popup, you can redirect him/her to the Google play store where he/she can choose to update.